# Referencing to an image/icon in the database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, icons

I have an app in which a user can create a new object (by filling a form), and one of the fields in the form is for choosing an icon for that specific object.
For that, I'd like to create a list of icons (that cannot be altered by the user through the app), and when a user chooses an icon, insert a **reference** to it in a column of the object.

I read about blobs, which are a possible solution to storing icons, but I think blobs are space-inefficient as depending on the image they can get quite big (I guess? correct me if I'm wrong...).

So my question is, **what is a solid way to insert a reference to an icon (or any image) to the database?**

Also, as a way to store a list of icons, I would create an ICONS table with icons and their reference... or is there a better way?

**The icons come from the drawable folder**

Comment: Where would these icons come from? drawable, assets, download from a server?

Comment: drawable. Sorry for not mentioning it earlier. I will edit my question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to have a table that contains all possible icons with their name. If you have a drawable "myImage.png", the name would be "myDrawable". You can then get the image resource id with [Context.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).